Why Grubbs test is not finding outliers?
I am new to Statistics. I am trying to find outliers in the given data using Grubbs method in python. But Grubbs is not able to find outliers for my data.
from outliers import smirnov_grubbs as grubbs
grubbs.max_test_outliers([201.35,214.17*1.2,196.32,212.66,202.95,202.66,206.28,201.93,219.59*1.2,212.14], alpha=0.05)
# expected [257, 263] but getting []

I suspect it is because of more outliers skewing the mean and standard deviation. Is there a way for me to specify a threshold (something like I suspect 3 outliers so you skip largest 3 data points in mean and standard deviation)

I had not heard of Grubbs' test before, so I looked it up. Per the National Institute of Standards, Grubbs' test:

is used to detect a single outlier in a univariate data set that
follows an approximately normal distribution.

They go on to recommend the Tietjen-Moore test or the generalized extreme deviate test for more than one outlier.
